# Django API permission decorator

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, permissions

**Objective:**
I want to allow some endpoint only to users with specifics permission.

For exemple to call the endpoint that allow the creation of users you need the permission "user.create"

**Problem:**

I tried to create a middle ware to use it with *decorator_from_middleware_with_args*

```
class PermissionMiddleware:

def __init__(self, view,permission):
    self.permission = permission

def process_request(self, request):
    if not request.user.has_perm(permission_name):
        if raise_exception:
            raise exceptions.PermissionDenied("Don't have permission")
        return False
    return True
```

Then inside my views i use the *decorator_from_middleware_with_args*

```
class UtilisateurViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
permission = decorator_from_middleware_with_args(PermissionMiddleware)

@permission('view_utilisateur')
def list(self, request):
    queryset = Utilisateur.objects.all()
    serializer = UtilisateurSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

But there is an error when i call the endpoint:

**AttributeError: 'UtilisateurViewSet' object has no attribute 'user'**

I think it's because the *django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware* is not executed yet.

Is there a way to define the order of the middlewares, or an other way to achieve what a want ?

Comment: So, the order of middlewares is exactly as they listed in MIDDLEWARES in settings.py. Have you tried to move SessionMiddleware upwards?

Comment: Actually, why exactly you need to use decorator? You can use `permission_classes`, but check for specific method (GET, POST etc) inside has_permission method of your class

Comment: I tried to put SessionMiddleware in the first position but it change nothing, i also tried to use `permission_classes`  but i would have to create a permission class for each model ? I would be easier to be able to define the permission with a decorator.

Comment: If i can't do it with the decorator, i'll do it with the `permission_classes` and create a class for each model, but i would prefere to make the decorator work

Comment: You can also define a factory, which will return a new class generated from your permission https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888339/how-to-make-a-python-factory-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found how to do exacly what i wanted, but i did achieve it in an other way.

I used the `permission_classes` and defined the required permissions in a Class, i'll do it for each viewset that i'll add.

```
class UtilisateurPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if view.action == "create":
        return bool(request.user.is_authenticated and (request.user.is_superuser or request.user.has_perm("utilisateur_create")))
    elif view.action == "retrieve":
        return bool(request.user.is_authenticated and (request.user.is_superuser or request.user.has_perm("utilisateur_retrieve")))
    elif view.action == "list":
        return bool(request.user.is_authenticated and (request.user.is_superuser or request.user.has_perm("utilisateur_list")))
    elif view.action == "destroy":
        return bool(request.user.is_authenticated and (request.user.is_superuser or request.user.has_perm("utilisateur_destroy")))
    elif view.action == "archive":
        return bool(request.user.is_authenticated and (request.user.is_superuser or request.user.has_perm("utilisateur_archive")))
    elif view.action in ['update', 'partial_update']:
        return bool(request.user.is_authenticated and (request.user.is_superuser or request.user.has_perm("utilisateur_update")))
    else:
        return False
```